# Linq-to-SQL foreign key is enum

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Linq-to-SQL task.

See pictures.

[image][image]

[image][image]

[image]

When I try to instantiate this, I get runtime exception 'The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type XAccountId which is a non-nullable value type'. When I change Type from XAccountId to int - everything works as expected. Why? How I can use my enum as Type of keys?

ADDITION: Although I set Nullable = true in property window, generated code is `private XAccountId _AccountId1 = default(XAccountId);`. So... DBML generator works incorrectly?

ADDITION 2: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee4f5703-570c-47bf-8003-bf15bd0f1441/map-nullable-enum related to my problem. DBML generator ignores CanBeNull="true" for enums.

Comment: It is still very unclear what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set type to be `XAccountId?` (with question mark). As error says, you can't assign nulls to value types, only to reference types; and `enum` is a value type. The alternative is to make you column not nullable.

Comment: I tried this before. It works. But. I am forced to set XAccountId? in XAccount as well, but it is not nullable by model.

Comment: If i'm reading your model right, you're setting it as nullable in model (second screen from the bottom), you've underlined it as nullable, shouldn't it be "nullable - false" then? how is it defined in db?

Comment: In XAccount it is non nullable (it is primary key in database). In XSourceSystem it may be null (no XAccount associated with XSourceSystem).